# Запустить браузер в "авторизованном" состоянии с помощью selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

При попытке передать аргумент

```
user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data
```

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                     "Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36")
browzer = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)
browzer.maximize_window()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Что может быть не так?
Как ещё можно подхватить драйвером уже ранее открытую вкладку, чтобы не мучаться с авторизацией?

Comment: Чтобы каждый раз не мучаться с авторизацией можно использовать профили браузера. Только не используйте свой основной, с которого сами сидите в интернете, во избежание неприятных казусов.

Comment: Помню как-то баловался с Selenium, профиль грузил через [`option.add_argument()`](https://github.com/dimithras/Xiaomi_game_clicker/blob/main/Xiaomi_clicker.py#L28), вполне рабочий вариант.

Comment: Так это именно я и попытался сделать, или что-то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: `user-data-dir` похоже лишний, достаточно просто передать путь вида `C:/Users/Some_User_Name/AppData/Local/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/User Data/Selenuim` c forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Строка

options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')

Должна выглядеть так:

options.add_argument('C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')

И тогда не возникает ошибка.